# fzf vim - when configured to display filenames of matched items, how to filter on just content and not the file names

Tags: fzf

I've configured my .vimrc file for GGrep:

```
command! -bang -nargs=* GGrep
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(
  \   ('git grep -i --line-number '.(isdirectory(expand(".git"))?'--untracked ':'--no-index ')).shellescape(<q-args>), 0,
  \   { 'dir': getcwd() }, <bang>0)
```

Note I've configured it to show the file path. However I don't want to search the file path. I just want to search the contents of the files. Does anyone know how to do this?

See below it's also filtering on the path.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume the arguments of grep are similar to fzf#run.

If that is the case you need to set:

`{ 'dir': getcwd(), 'options': '-n 2'}`

The -n tells the column that is relevant for the search. You can do `man fzf` for more details.